# NetSuite custom field - Formula to remove special characters

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, saved-searches

I have a current saved search formula that groups values from two fields in lowercase, and It also replaces any spaces with hyphen. Currently it also removes two special characters including period and forward slash. I am now trying to modify this formula to also remove 2 additional characters including Apostrophe (‘) and quotation mark (“)
Following is the current formula: TRANSLATE(LOWER(CONCAT({custitem38}||'-', {custitem16})), ' /.', '--')
This worked for me: TRANSLATE(LOWER(CONCAT({custitem38}||'-', {custitem16})), ' "/.', '--')

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`TRANSLATE(LOWER(CONCAT({custitem38}||'-', {custitem16})), ' "/.', '--')

Answer (score 0):

This might work
TRANSLATE(LOWER(CONCAT({custitem38}||'-', {custitem16})),'‘"/"/.', '--')